# 2015 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2015 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 10):

Note that I've decided after being a moderator on this site for about 3 years, that I'm stepping down. It's been an exciting time, but I've got enough other commitments that it's time to let someone else manage this site.

Good luck to all the candidates!

Comment: I noted that there are two positions available.

Comment: I'm stepping down, and there's an extra person coming in. Thus, there will be two new mods.

Comment: Thanks for all the hard work you've put into the site!  You've been a great mod, and your work has been appreciated :)

Comment: Seconded. I can't think of any of your decisions that I've disagreed with :-)

Comment: Thirded. Thanks.

Comment: Amen <_____filler________>

Comment: Does the fact that there are 8 upvotes means that you were popular... or that your decision to step down was popular? :)

Comment: I'll go with both;-)

Comment: @DVK: 8 people have nominated themselves to replace him. Make of that what you will.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - *gasp* There's also eight-fold path to enlightenment in Yoga Sutra. This is clearly connected!

Comment: Someone else should just upvote this so these conspiracies stop...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Now 9 upvotes. All is well.